# When I click hyperlink, the parent div disappears.

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone explain why when I click in the sub-menu, the whole area disappears?

You can see my CSS & HTML here:
http://jsfiddle.net/x7ehtscp/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">



<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar first"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar second"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar third"></span>
            </button>

          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left ">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Bla</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <div class="yamm-content"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> </ul></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's working as expected for me? Clicking it slides the menu down as normal, clicking it again slides it up as normal. What browser **and** version are you trying to do this in?

Comment: works for me as expected on Chrome 39, Firefox 33 and IE 11

Comment: My apologies. When the link is clicked, I'd prefer if the user was just taken to that web page rather than the dropdown disappearing. See this updated with an actual hyperlink: http://jsfiddle.net/x7ehtscp/1/

Comment: it works fine, jsfiddle will not redirect you to google due to security reasons. change the link to a page within jsfiddle, and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/x7ehtscp/2/

Comment: But why do all the links disappear after clicking one?

Comment: because instead of renavigating it reloads the same page. - jsfiddle thing. try it locally using a `.html` file and you will see.

Comment: Strangely, I have tried it locally and it does the same thing. Are you able to replicate this issue locally, away from jsFiddle?

Comment: let me understand, is the problem that it will not follow the hyperlink? or you just want it not to close the submenu before navigating to the new page?

Comment: That's correct. When clicked, I don't want the submenu to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the submenu from closing:

```
$('.dropdown .navbar-left a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7ehtscp/3/)

In the Fiddle I've also added `preventDefault()` to prevent following the `#` target which is not needed to keep the submenu open.